# Reuse trained weights in TensorFlow model without reinitialization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow model that looks roughly like:

```
class MyModel():

def predict(self, x):
    with tf.variable_scope("prediction", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        W_1 = tf.get_variable("weight", shape=[64,1], dtype=tf.float64)
        b_1 = tf.get_variable("bias", shape=[1], dtype=tf.float64)
        y_hat = tf.matmul(x, W_1) + b_1
    return y_hat


def train_step(self, x, y):
    with tf.variable_scope("optimization"):
        y_hat = self.predict(x)
        loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_hat)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)
    return train_step


def __call__(self, x):
    return self.predict(x)
```

I can instantiate the model like `my_model = MyModel()` and then train it using `sess.run(my_model.train_step(x, y))`, but if I want to predict on a different tensor after training like `sess.run(my_model.predict(x_new))`, I get a `FailedPreconditionError`.

It seems like the object's `__call__` function is not reusing the weights as intended, but adds new weights to the graph, which are then uninitialized. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is to define the weights as attributes of the network and not inside the predict function, same remark for the optimizer and train_step. Maybe it could help because `train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)` look at the whole graph.